# C-programming loop wont stop with scanf!=0

Tags: c, scanf

What is wrong with this ? Also, I have to use `scanf()`. It is supposed to read any integers and sum them, the loop is to stop when `0` is entered..

```
main (void){

int a;
int r=0;

while(scanf(" %d",&a)){
    r=r+a;
    }

printf("the sum is %d\n",r);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read `scanf` documentation about its return values?

Comment: it should be while(scanf(" %d",&a)!=0) there. what do you mean?

Comment: @riczreich Please read the documentation. You seem to have a misconception about what `scanf` returns.

Comment: To find documentation about any standard C or Posix or GNU function google `man functionname` or type it at command line if using Linux/Unix.

Comment: Why do you have to use `scanf`?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [man](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/)

> These functions **return the number of input items assigned.  This
>   can be
>        fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of a matching fail-
>        ure.  Zero indicates that, although there was input available, no conver-
>        sions were assigned; typically this is due to an invalid input character,
>        such as an alphabetic character for a `%d' conversion.**
>        The value EOF is
>        returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion such as an end-
>        of-file occurs.  If an error or end-of-file occurs after conversion has
>        begun, the number of conversions which were successfully completed is
>        returned.

So, that pretty much explains what is returned by `scanf()`.

You can solve the problem by adding  `( 1 == scanf("%d", &a) && a != 0 )` as the condition in your while loop like

```
int main (void)
  {

    int a;
    int r=0;

    while( 1 == scanf("%d", &a) && a != 0 )
      {
         r=r+a;
      }

    printf("the sum is %d\n",r);

    return 0;
  }
```

Also note that you have to specify the type of main as `int main()`.

I would also like to add that the loop will end when you enter a character like `'c'` ( or a string ) and it will show the sum of all the numbers you entered before entering the character.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` doesn't return what it has written to the variable. It returns the total number of *items* successfully filled.

**EDIT**:

You would be much better off using `fgets()` to read from `stdin` and then using `sscanf()` to get the integer, which you can check against `0`.

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

int main (void)
{
    int a;
    int r = 0;
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
    while(1) {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
        sscanf(buffer, "%d", &a);
        if(!a)
            break;
        r = r + a;
    }

    printf("the sum is %d\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so,how can i do this..im supposed to use scanf.

Comment: @riczreich use `scanf()` in this instead of `fgets()` and `sscanf()`, but be advised that `scanf()` is unsafe from buffer overflow.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan why would `scanf` be unsafe regarding buffer overflows? I mean, any more unsafe than everything else in C. Just tell it buffer sizes when scanfing strings.